# Change TTL connect-mongo expiration option to session time

Tags: mongodb, express-session, ttl, connect-mongo, expired-sessions

I'm trying to store sessions into MongoDB. The problem I'm facing is that I can't set the MongoDB TTL to the session duration.
Here's my code :

```
app.use(session({
    secret: md5("test"),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/test-db' }),
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));
```

If I don't store the session inside a database, it's simple because I have to remove the store key and as the maxAge of my cookie is not defined, it will last while the user hasn't closed the browser.
But if I store inside MongoDB, as maxAge or expires is not defined, it will set by default  an expiration of 14 days which I don't want.
It's really annoying because if a restart my browser I will have multiples sessions for only one client.

So do you have a solution please ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand your comment "I can't set the MongoDB TTL to the session duration".  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @barrypicker yes sorry, when you store a session on MongoDB you can define when the data will last on the db (the TLL 'time to live'). I want that this duration last the session duration.

Comment: Database sessions were introduced to MongoDB in version 3.6.  By default a session can live for 30 minutes before they expire.  After they expire a reaper process cleans up expired sessions every 5 minutes.  While you can add database startup parameters to change these values it is recommended to keep the defaults.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes for more information.